# Rotman Group Theory Exercise

Tags: group-theory

> Assume the fact $\vert G \vert$ is square-free $\implies$ $G$ is not simple.
> Prove that if $\vert G \vert = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ with primes $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_n$ then $G$ contains a normal $p_n$-Sylow.

Except the fact that Sylow theorem states $(\# \text{ of $p_n$-Sylow}) = 1 + p_nk$ and this number divides $\vert G \vert$, I do not really know how to proceed. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Since $G$ is not simple, it has a normal subgroup. Use induction.

Comment: @leoli1 I think proving this without using the hint might be hard. Note that, for example, $5*7*11*13 \bmod 139=1$, so if $|G|=5*7*11*13*19*23*139$, you will need to work.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, you are right, I somehow thought we could just look at the prime factors of the number of $p_n$-Sylow subgroups

Answer (score 1):

As David A. Craven suggests, we prove by induction on the order of $G$.
Let $H\triangleleft G$, we consider two cases.

1. If $p_n$ divides $\vert H\vert$,
   then from the induction hypothesis $p_n$-Sylow subgroup $P$ is normal in $H$ and hence $P$ is also normal in $G$ by the conjugation property of Sylow subgroups.
2. If $p_n$ does not divide $\vert H \vert$, then by induction hypothesis $G/H$ has a normal $p_n$-Sylow subgroup and its preimage in $G$ is normal so we reduce to the first case.

Comment: Yes, but your only issue is what if $|H|=|G|/p_n$?

Comment: ...then we replace $H$ by $H$'s $p_{n-1}$-Sylow subgroup and since it is normal in $G$ for the same reason in 1, is that correct?

Comment: Seems right, except what if $n=2$?

Comment: ...the number of $p_2$-Sylow subgroups $= 1 + k \cdot p_2$ divides $p_1$. Since $p_2 > p_1$, $k=0$ so the $p_2$-Sylow subgroup is normal.